# Enzyme React Adapter mount is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, enzyme, mount

I have problem with testing React component.

In the context of this issue, I received a "boilerplate" were I was installing dependencies as my App goes growing. My code runs fine, no console errors, and perform everything it must. I have adding some tiny testing for Backend that runs fine also, but can't make it work ( Don't know how really) to run this Frontend one:

Here's my component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector,useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import style from './form.module.css';
import { getTemperaments,postRaze } from '../../actions/index'

function Form() {
  const[errors,setErrors]= useState({name:""});
  const valueTemp = useSelector((state) => state.temperaments)
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  function validate(input){
    let errors={};
   
    if(parseInt(input.height_min) >= parseInt(input.height_max)){
      errors.name = 'Initial value cant be greater than final value!'
    }else{
      setErrors({name:""});
    }
    
    if(parseInt(input.weight_min) >= parseInt(input.weight_max)){
      errors.name = 'Initial value cant be greater than final value!'
    }else{
      setErrors({name:""});
    }
    
    if(parseInt(input.life_min) >= parseInt(input.life_max)){
      errors.name = 'Initial value cant be greater than final value!'
    }else{
      setErrors({name:""});
    }
    
    return errors;
  }

  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    name: "",
    height_min: "",
    height_max: "",
    weight_min: "",
    weight_max: "",
    life_min: "",
    life_max: "",
    image: "",
    temperament: [],
  })
  

  async function handleSubmit(event) { 
    if(errors.name !== undefined){
      document.getElementById('form').reset();
      return alert('You have been warned, but attemp to create anyway. Now form will reset!');
    }
    const myModel={ 
      name:input.name,
      height: input.height_min + " - " + input.height_max,
      weight:input.weight_min + " - " + input.weight_max,
      life: input.life_min + " - " + input.life_max,
      image:input.image,
      temperament:input.temperament,
    } 
    event.preventDefault();
    dispatch(postRaze(myModel)); 
    alert('Your Dog has been created!')         ;
    setInput({
      name: "",
      height_min: "",
      height_max: "",
      weight_min: "",
      weight_max: "",
      life_min: "",
      life_max: "",
      image: "",
      temperament: [],  
    })
    setErrors({});

  }

  
  function handleSelect(e){  
    setInput({
      ...input, temperament:[...input.temperament, +e.target.value ]
    })  
  }
   
  function handleChange(e) {  
    setErrors(validate({
      ...input,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }));
    setInput({
      ...input,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }
    
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getTemperaments());
  },[dispatch]);

  return (
    <section className={style.container}>

      <form id="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit} className={style.formul}>

        <div>
          <input className={style.orderLarge}
            placeholder="Name"
            type="text"
            name="name"
            required="required"
            value={input.name}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        
        <div className={style.MinMax}>
          <p>Height values:</p>
          <div className={style.areaMinMax}>
            <input className={style.order}
              placeholder="Min"
              type="text"
              name="height_min"
              required="required"
              value={input.height_min}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <input className={style.order}
              placeholder="Max"
              type="text"
              name="height_max"
              required="required"
              value={input.height_max}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className={style.MinMax}>
          <p>Weight values:</p>
          <div className={style.areaMinMax}>
            <input className={style.order}
              placeholder="Min"
              type="text"
              name="weight_min"
              required="required"
              value={input.weight_min}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input className={style.order}
              placeholder="Max"
              type="text"
              name="weight_max"
              required="required"
              value={input.weight_max}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div className={style.MinMax}>
        <p>Life.. values    :</p>
        <div className={style.areaMinMax}>
            <input className={style.order}
              placeholder="Min"
              type="text"
              name="life_min"
              required="required"
              value={input.life_min}
               onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div >
          <div>
            <input className={style.order}
              placeholder="Max"
              type="text"
              name="life_max"
              required="required"
              value={input.life_max}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div >
        </div>


        <div>
          <input className={style.orderLarge}
          placeholder="Load image path"
            type="text"
            name="image"
            required="required"
            value={input.image}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div >
        {errors.name && (
          <h4 className={style.danger}>{errors.name}</h4>
        )}
        <select className={style.orderLarge} onChange={handleSelect}
          value={input.temperament[input.temperament.length - 1]}required>
          <option value="">Temperaments:</option>
          {valueTemp.map(e => (
            <option key={e.id} value={e.id}>{e.name}</option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <div style={{color:'burlywood'}}>{[input.temperament.map(i => valueTemp.find( v => v.id === i)?.name + ", ")]}</div>
    
        <div className={style.footer}>
          <input className={style.orderLarge} type="submit" value="Create Race" />
          <Link className={style.order} to='/home'>Home!</Link>
        </div>

      </form>
    </section>
  )
}



export default  Form;
```

About the test, I just need a simple code that check for existing inputs:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { mount } from '@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17';
import Form  from './index';

describe('<Form /> Mounted', () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<Form />);
  });
  

  it('El form debe tener un input con name "name" y type "text"', () => {
    const { container } = render(<Form />)
    const element = container.querySelectorAll('input')[0]
    expect(element.type).toBe('text');
    expect(element.name).toBe('username');
  });

  it('El form debe tener un input con name "height_min" y type "text"', () => {
    const { container } = render(<Form />)
    const element = container.querySelectorAll('input')[1]
    expect(element.type).toBe('text');
    expect(element.name).toBe('height_min');
  });
})
```

This is the console error:

```
 TypeError: (0 , _enzymeAdapterReact.mount) is not a function

       9 |   let wrapper;
      10 |   beforeEach(() => {
    > 11 |     wrapper = mount(<Form />);
         |               ^
      12 |   });
      13 |
      14 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Form/Form.test.js:11:15)
```

And here is the package.json:

```
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.6.3",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17#configuration) only provide an adapter for React 17 for Enzyme. You should import the `mount` function from the `enzyme` package. It should be

```js
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from '@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

// use mount function.
```

Comment: We re getting close, its seems! I've added your lines: now im getting this:     could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider> at
`
       9 | function Form() {
      10 |   const[errors,setErrors]= useState({name:""});
    > 11 |   const valueTemp = useSelector((state) => state.temperaments)
         |                     ^
      12 |   const dispatch = useDispatch(); `

Comment: @MartinGonzalez I advise you use [redux-mock-store](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-mock-store) package to create mock store and use it like `mount(<Provider store={store}><Form/></Provider>)`

Comment: Allready have a <Provider store={store}><App/></Provider> that envelopes all the App. Please excuse me to ask, but : Aren´t Provider store allready declared?

Comment: @MartinGonzalez You are testing the `Form` component, not `App`, it's not wrapped by the `Provider`. Since you use `useSelector` in the `Form` component, you need to use `Provider` wrap the `Form` in your test case

Comment: Ok @slideshowp2, I added Provider: ` beforeEach(() => {
    // wrapper = mount(<Form />);
    <BrowserRouter>
    mount(<Provider store={store}><Form/></Provider>)
    </BrowserRouter>
  });`  Now hooks inside Form throw this error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>